# How can I ensure NodaTime objects always get 'stringified' to ISO formats?

Tags: nodatime

When we use the NodaTime objects, it's a bit too easy to get the wrong format.
For example, we use string interpolation to construct uri's, but we really want the yyyy-MM-dd format. Same goes for logging, we don't really want any other format.

```cs
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2020, 8, 10);
string toString = $"{date}"; // "den 10 augusti 2020"
logger.LogInformation("Date: {Date}", date); // "Date: Monday, 10 August 2020"
```

The documentation for ToString (which is used for the 2nd line above) states:
"The value of the current instance in the default format pattern ("D"), using
the current thread's culture to obtain a format provider."

If I change the current culture to InvariantCulture, I now get both of the above lines to show "Monday, 10 August 2020", which is better because they are consistent but neither is the yyyy-MM-dd format.

```cs
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Ideally though, I would want to only customize how NodaTime objects are "stringified" to avoid any other undesired side effects of changing culture. Is there any help to get here or am I stuck?

edit:

I made a console application to have a minimal reproducible example

```cs
Console.WriteLine(new LocalDate(2020,8,13));
Console.WriteLine(ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now);
```

and with that I got the following output:

```
den 13 augusti 2020
2020-08-13T08:39:16 UTC+02 (+02)
2020-08-13 08:39:16
2020-08-13 08:39:16 +02:00
```

I would have liked if LocalDate had a default output of 2020-08-13 which is more useful in logs as well as string interpolation, for example: `var uri = $"api/orders?date={localDate}"`

Comment: Why not explicitely state the format, like `string toString = $"{date:yyyy-MM-dd}";`?

Comment: Because it's too easy to forget that. We use Seq as logging, and it's very common to log using the example shown with tokens. Naturally, if I have to then that is the way we will have to do it but I would rather change the default format if I can

Comment: You can't change the default format of Noda Time types any more than you can of `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`. You could always set the current culture to one which has an appropriate `DateTimeFormatInfo`, if you want... but I don't know whether that would satisfy you as an answer. Let me know if it would, and I'll write an example.

Comment: (Thanks for an awesome library).

Comment: `DateTime:  2020-08-11T12:44:26.5456605Z | 2020-08-11 14:44:26`
  
`DateTimeOffset: 2020-08-11 14:44:26 +02:00 | 2020-08-11 14:44:26 +02:00`

`LocalDate: Tuesday, 11 August 2020 | den 11 augusti 2020`

`ZonedDateTime: 2020-08-11T14:44:26 Europe/Stockholm (+02) | 2020-08-11T14:44:26 Europe/Stockholm (+02)`

With the bcl types I never ran into this issue because their default is something I expect to see (even if some of them are a bit hard to read), unfortunately LocalDate is being formatted differently. Do you know an suitable DateTimeFormatInfo?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, it worked differently when writing a comment and apparently enter means send rather than new line.

Comment: "With the bcl types I never ran into this issue because their default is something I expect to see" - but they're not ISO-8601. `LocalDate` is formatted as a `DateTime` would be using the "long date" format. It's not clear to me how you formatted the `DateTime` values there (or in fact any of them) - it would be better to edit that into the question, along with a [mcve] to produce the values. As for a suitable `DateTimeFormatInfo` - I don't believe there are any *existing* ones, but you could clone one and then set the format. Again, if you'd like that as an answer, I could write it up.

Comment: I updated the question as suggested. Thank you for your patience with me.
You are most welcome to show how to accomplish this with DateTimeFormatInfo and I'd accept that as an answer if that is the easiest way to "customize" the output of NodaTime objects globally.

Comment: Ah, so that's just using "whatever your system culture is" - on my system that shows 13/08/2020 09:44:06 for the third line. Using the invariant culture shows 08/13/2020 09:44:26 - neither being ISO-like in the way that your third line is. Working on an "iso-culture" now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of achieving this is to use a `CultureInfo` that defaults to ISO-8601 formatting. It's reasonably easy to create that, starting with the invariant culture:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var isoCulture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
        var format = isoCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        format.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        format.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
        format.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF";
        format.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF";
        format.LongDatePattern = format.ShortDatePattern;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = isoCulture;
        Console.WriteLine(new LocalDate(2020, 8, 13));
        Console.WriteLine(ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2020-08-13
2020-08-13T09:52:18 UTC+01 (+01)
2020-08-13 09:52:18.7351962
2020-08-13 09:52:18.7356716 +01:00
```

I believe .NET just uses "date pattern" {space} "time pattern" when formatting a `DateTime`, so I don't *think* there's a way of getting a `T` in there. But hey, the `LocalDate` output is what you wanted :)

Comment: Why did we clone `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` here?